# Putting a Hyperlink in Excel into an Outlook Email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, hyperlink

I have an Excel document that is used to send out daily information (huddle notes) for work. I have it set up with macros where you can click a button, and an email is generated that contains the relevant information. At the bottom of this Excel sheet is a hyperlink to a Microsoft Form that we use as a feedback form that employees may use. Rather than having the entire url showing, the text that is shown is simply "Feedback Form". When the hyperlink is clicked in Excel, it works fine and opens up the form. However, once the Excel sheet is put into an Outlook email, the text still says "Feedback Form" but it is unable to be clicked. I'm not sure if this is due to the macro using html when the email is generated? Regardless, I could use some help with how to get the hyperlink to work again in the email. Below is the code I have for the email macro.

```
Sub EmailHuddleNotes

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Dim rng As Range
Dim Outlook As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Sheets("Huddle Notes").Range("B1:I66").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    
End With
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next

With OutlookMail
    .To = "email.com"
    .Cc = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Huddle Notes"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set Outlook = Nothing

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim txtstr As Object
    Dim File As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    File = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    rng.Copy
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(1)
With Wb.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    With Wb.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=File, _
         Sheet:=Wb.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=Wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtstr = obj.GetFile(File).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = txtstr.readall
    txtstr.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    Wb.Close savechanges:=False
    Kill File
    Set txtstr = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Wb = Nothing
End Function
```

[image: Hyperlink in Excel]

Comment: It seems you want to go with VBA, I would suggest to consider Office Script if your excel version allows it, then you can use Power Automate to send the email.